# Is it possible to download a compiled c++ binary and load it run time on iOS?

Tags: android, c++, ios, mobile, dylib

I'm curious about the dynamic loading of c++ game logic on mobile platforms. On Android there is a possibility to load newly downloaded *.so files in the app, which allows quicker game updates than going through the play store testing process. There's a bit of explanation [here](https://blog.hike.in/reduce-the-size-of-your-app-by-moving-so-files-to-over-the-air-b51ca9dfdaf2).

My question is about the iOS possibilities regarding this kind of behavior. I couldn't find a reliable source with information about this, but I really hope the community can help me out. :)

**Is it possible to download a compiled c++ binary and load it run time on iOS?**

Comment: No, you can't because the code won't be signed by Apple. It is also expressly prohibited by the App Store review guidelines. [2.5.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements)

Comment: Thx for the info!